# iOSシミュレータで日本語入力を行うには？

Tags: ios

iOSシミュレータで開発を行っているのですが、ソフトウェアキーボードが英語入力です。
日本語入力を行うにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xcode6.1であれば、絵文字切り替えだけ＆日本語入力できない不具合を、バグレポートとして報告済みです。
同じ報告があると言われ、クローズされてしまいましたが、まだ直ってないようですね。

Comment: マイナス投票された方、できれば理由をコメントとして残していってもらえると役に立ちます。(単に質問への回答になっていないだけなのか、回答の内容が間違っているのか、など)

Answer (score 3):

キーボードの左下に、地球のマークが表示されていますか？
[image: キーボード画像]

表示されていない場合には、設定 -> 一般 -> キーボード -> キーボードを選択し、「新しいキーボードを追加」で日本語（ローマ字）を追加すると、地球のマークが表示されるようになります。
複数キーボードが追加されているときは、地球のマークが出ていると思いますが、もしもローマ字入力の日本語キーボードが追加されていない場合には、追加すれば、Macのハードウェアキーボードで入力すれば文字入力できるようになります。

なお、言語環境が「日本語」ではなく、「English」の場合あるいはそれ以外の場合も、同等の操作でキーボードを追加できます。

正直、本質問は、ほぼiOSの使い方についての質問だと思います...そのほかシミュレータについての詳しい説明は、[Apple公式のiOSシュミレータユーザガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/devcenter/ios/library/documentation/iOSSimulatorUserGuide.pdf)という素晴らしいものが、日本語のリソースとしてありますので一読されることをお勧めします。

Comment: 回答内容と直接関係ありませんが: 「iOSの使い方についての質問はオフトピックとした方がよいか」について、[メタに議題としてあげました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/367/30)。思うところあればぜひ意見をください。もしオフトピックとした方がいい、とまでは意図されていなかったとしても、ご意見いただければうれしいです

Answer (score 3):

Xcodeの

[Product]=>[Scheme]=>[EditScheme]

で
Runのところにある
Arguments Passed On Launch
に

```
-AppleLanguages (ja)
```

を追加してください
これで日本語モードでシミュレータが起動すると思います

Answer (score 1):

iPhoneシミュレータ内で言語設定を日本語にできませんか？

余談ですが、たまにバグって入力できない時は、コピペのコマンド（Ctrl + c,Ctrl + v）を入れてからシミュレーター内のテキストフィールを長押しして表示されるペーストのポップアップをタップすると入力できます。